# How to convert large exponential values to integer/decimal format in Marklogic?

Tags: xquery, marklogic-9, marklogic-10

I have an exponential value for e.g. `3.22122E+23`

In Marklogic when I try- `xs:decimal(3.22122E+23)`
I get this error:

> [1.0-ml] XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) xs:decimal(xs:double("3.22122E23")) -- Invalid cast: xs:double("3.22122E23") cast as xs:decimal

A lower value for e.g. `xs:decimal(3.22122E+18)` gives me the correct result i.e. `3221220000000000000`.

I see that this is because of decimal overflow and cannot be represented as a decimal data type but is there any way in Marklogic to handle and calculate such huge values?

Same question applies for the negative values(`3.22122E-23`) where I can handle and display data above 20 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to clarify what kind of logic or calculations you are trying to accomplish and why exactly you need to convert the value to decimal.  For example, to "display" the double value, you can use the standard format-number function without any conversion to decimal:

```
let $x := xs:double(3.22122E+23)
return format-number($x,"#,##0.00")
```

yields:

```
322,122,000,000,000,000,000,000.00
```

See https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:format-number for details regarding `fn:format-number()` usage.

See https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/487/0/marklogic-server-and-the-decimal-type-implementation for details of the limitations of the `xs:decimal` type.

Comment: There is a requirement to display the exponential values in expanded format but the above solution is not working. It gives this error-  [1.0-ml] XDMP-DECOVRFLW: (err:FOAR0002) fn:format-number(xs:double("3.22122E23"), "#,##0.00") -- Decimal overflow

Comment: I am able to recreate the same error with MarkLogic.  I will leave it up to the MarkLogic experts to comment on whether this is a MarkLogic defect.  It does not appear this error is an expected result of the W3C spec.  I get the expected result in Saxon, Zorba, and xidel processors.

Comment: I have filed a MarkLogic bug for this, as it does seem like it *should* work, but doesn't at the moment.